# Which JavaScript features are available in Google Apps scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The manual literally says that "Apps Script is based in JS 1.6, plus *a few features* of 1.7 and 1.8" (emphasis mine). However, I haven't found a reference of which *few* are really there. ArrayBuffer, for instance, is not. Is there a reference somewhere or a hack like `Object.keys(window)` that yields what's available?

Comment: Map is perfectly functional... did you meet ant issue ?

Comment: It was just not recognized by the IDE. But I'll erase that, if you say it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript that runs in a `.gs` code file, runs on Google's server.  It's server side code.  There is no window object for a `.gs` code file.  One useful service for storing data is the `Cache Service`

[Google Documentation Link - Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/)

You just need to search the Google Apps Script documentation for Classes, Methods and Properties that are available.  There *is* auto-complete in the code editor, which should give you an idea of what's available to Apps Script Classes.  There are classes in Apps Script that are specific to Apps Script, like:
 UI service or the HTML service, and the Content service.

If you are looking for what is available to client side JavaScript in the browser, that's different.  You *can* use client side JavaScript and jQuery with HTML Service.

Comment: Using the auto-complete means checking, one by one, all features, and the fact that they don't work (as it happens with Map) does not mean it's not there. I was just wondering if all features actually used by the GAS interpreter were in a single place.

Comment: I don't know of any official documentation that lists which JavaScript features have been implemented.